# Netbeans subversion right margin

Tags: svn, ide, netbeans

How do I change the color coding in the right margin of Netbeans? The part where Subversion keeps track of the changes, deletes, adds, etc.  The only reference I've found was the Netbeans Subversion guide that tells you what they are, but doesn't explain how to configure or disable it.  (is it even configurable?)

So I did some more searching and one site mentioned changing a config file to alter the color scheme for the files in the file browser, does anyone know if a config file exists for the right margin? I want to disable the Subversion part of it since it is interfering with useful things like breakpoints, errors, and warnings (too much clutter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following has been verified on Netbeans 6.1 :

1. Go to tools > Options
2. Click on 'fonts and Colours'
3. Select 'Diff' in the tab window that appears.
4. Select your preferred colours:

[alt text http://img49.imageshack.us/img49/1954/diffpu3.jpg](http://img49.imageshack.us/img49/1954/diffpu3.jpg)

Click Ok, once you're satisfied.

That's it.

Comment: when you do that it only changes the side bar when you do a diff, but the color scheme doesn't show up in the normal code window.  That's why I was looking for config files to edit.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for trying though, if no solution comes up you'll get the bounty in 6 days :)

Comment: Aaw... I'm sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

looks like this doesn't work and there's 2 open cases about this issue.

```
http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=134346
http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=104632
```

Comment: You might want to upvote the issue http://www.netbeans.org/issues/showvotes.cgi?voteon=134346, I have done so it might then get resolved for Netbeans 7.0

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, that might not be configurable. However, you might consider asking it on the NetBeans users mailing list/forum. More on this at http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ

Best of Luck!